# Boundedness of the multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function. Let $M_f$ be the multiplication operator whose domain is those $g\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ for which $fg \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu).$

If $f$ is essentially bounded, then I can prove that $M_f$ is a bounded operator with $\|M_f\|=\|f\|_{\infty}$ where $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the essential supremum of $f.$

I am unable to prove the converse! Here is my attempt.

Suppose $f$ is not essentially bounded, then $E_n=\{w \in\Omega: |f(w)| \geq n\}$ has positive measure for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ So, if I can find for every $n$ a non-zero $g$ in the domain of $M_f$ that vanishes outside $E_n$ then we get
\begin{align*}
\|M_f(g)\|^2&= \int_{\Omega} |fg|^2 \\
&= \int_{E_n} |f|^2 |g|^2 \\
&\geq n^2 \|g\|^2
\end{align*}
which implies $\|M_f\| \geq n$ proving that $M_f$ is not bounded.

But I don't see how I can find such $g.$

P.S. If we assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is $\sigma-$finite, then I can find a subset of $F_{n,m}$ of $E_n$ of finite positive measure with $n \leq |f|< n+m$ on $F_{n,m},$ and let $g=\mathbb{1}_{F_{n,m}}.$

Answer (score 3):

The claim is not true in general. If $ \mu$ is such that $\mu(A)=+\infty$ for all $A\ne\emptyset$, then $L^2=\{0\}$ is trivial, and $f$ can be arbitrary.

If the measure space is such that every set $A$ of positive measure contains a subset of positive and finite measure then the claim is true. $\sigma$-finiteness is sufficient, as you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the example, @daw. I was wondering, what would be the necessary and sufficient condition for the claim to be true?

Comment: Since I am only interested in the finite positive measures of $E_n,$ I think it is also sufficient that the sigma subalgebra generated by $f$ be sigma finite.